# How do I add a custom button after video finishes playing

Tags: javascript, html

So I have already coded other stuff to appear after a background video finishes playing using this javascript

```
var vid = document.getElementById("bgvid");
var vid2 = document.getElementById('akiratrailer');
vid.onended = function() {myFunction()}; 
function myFunction() {
vid2.style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("headline2").innerHTML = "stuff";
document.getElementById("headline3").innerHTML = "stuff";
};
```

How would I add a custom button (I already have the CSS for the button) to this javascript so that it may show up after the background video finishes along with the other stuff?

This is my the html for the button

```
<a href='newpage.html' class='button'>blah blah blah</a>
```

my website for reference [My Website](http://andiviaandes.com/akira.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var vid = document.getElementById( 'bgvid' ),
    vid2 = document.getElementById( 'content' );

vid.onended = function() {
    vid2.style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById( 'headline2' ).innerHTML = 'stuff';
    document.getElementById( 'headline3' ).innerHTML = 'stuff';
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box
}
body {
    margin: 0
}
#bgvid {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%
}
#content {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    overflow-y: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: #f1f1f1;
    text-align: center
}
#akiratrailer {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50%
}
.button {
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: none;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none
}
.button:hover {
    background: #ddd;
    color: black
}
```

```html
<video autoplay muted id="bgvid">
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/rain.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<div id="content">
    <h2 id="headline2"></h2>
    <video id="akiratrailer" controls>
        <source src="http://andiviaandes.com/videos/akiratrailer.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <h2 id="headline3"></h2>
    <a href='#' class='button'>blah blah blah</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you could either generate the button dynamically using the below code in onended callback

```
var button = document.createElement('button');
var node = document.createTextNode('Click me');
button.appendChild(node);
button.classList.add('button');
body.appendChild(button); //or any other parent element you wish to add the button to
```

or just simply add the button in HTML, set up the class and adjust display to 'display: none' and change it similarily to how you manipulate the headlines right now.

Here's the jsbin with a working example: http://jsbin.com/pepidedimo/edit?html,css,js,console,output